# Swift - Find character at several positions within string

Tags: string, swift

In Swift, with the following string: `"this is a string"`, how to obtain an array of the indexes where the character `" "` (space) is present in the string?

Desired result: `[4,7,9]`

I've tried:

```
let spaces: NSRange = full_string.rangeOfString(" ")
```

But that only returns 4, not all the indexes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple approach — **updated for Swift 5.6 (Xcode 13)**:

```
let string = "this is a string"

let offsets = string
    .enumerated()
    .filter { $0.element == " " }
    .map { $0.offset }

print(offsets) // [4, 7, 9]
```

How it works:

- `enumerated()` enumerates the characters of the string
- `filter` removes the characters for which the characters *aren't* spaces
- `map` converts the array of tuples to an array of just the indices

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Swift 1.2 using Regex

```
func searchPattern(pattern : String, inString string : String) -> [Int]?
{
  let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(), error: nil)
  return regex?.matchesInString(string, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location:0, length:count(string)))
               .map { ($0 as! NSTextCheckingResult).range.location }
}

let string = "this is a string"

searchPattern("\\s\\S", inString : string) // [4, 7, 9]
searchPattern("i", inString : string) // [2, 5, 13]
```

Comment: Here is a puzzle for you: `searchPattern(" ", inString : "  ")` returns `Optional([4])` :)